# Android: Starting a service to play radio channels

Tags: android, service

I am trying to make a service that plays in background which is unbounded. I have walked myself through some of the example codes on the internet but I can't get my application to play the radio when I'm calling the service class.

Please have a look at the code and tell me where I am going wrong... When I call MyService class from ArmanFMRadio onClick It toasts "My Service Created" & "My Service Started" but doesnt get to play the audio for the radio stream link. I've checked it otherwise and the link seems fine, so problem lies somewhere in the code to my understanding:

```
package com.etc.etcc;

public class ArmanFMRadio extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

private ProgressBar playSeekBar;
private Button buttonPlay;
private Button buttonStopPlay;
private MediaPlayer player;


/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.armanfm);
    initializeUIElements();
    //initializeMediaPlayer();

}

private void initializeUIElements() {

    playSeekBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
    playSeekBar.setMax(100);
    playSeekBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    buttonPlay = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonPlay);
    buttonPlay.setOnClickListener(this);

    buttonStopPlay = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonStopPlay);
    buttonStopPlay.setEnabled(false);
    buttonStopPlay.setOnClickListener(this);

}

private void initializeMediaPlayer() {
    player = new MediaPlayer();


        try {
            player.setDataSource("http://50.117.26.26:3953/Live");
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    player.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(new OnBufferingUpdateListener() {

        public void onBufferingUpdate(MediaPlayer mp, int percent) {
            playSeekBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            playSeekBar.setSecondaryProgress(percent);
            Log.i("Buffering", "" + percent);

        }
    });
}

public void onClick(View v) {
    switch(v.getId()){
    case R.id.buttonPlay:

        playSeekBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        buttonStopPlay.setEnabled(true);
        buttonPlay.setEnabled(false);
        startService(new Intent(this, MyService.class));

        //startPlaying();
        break;
    case R.id.buttonStopPlay:
        stopPlaying();
        break;
    } 

}

private void startPlaying() {
    buttonStopPlay.setEnabled(true);
    buttonPlay.setEnabled(false);

    playSeekBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    player.prepareAsync();
    player.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {

        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {

        player.start();

        }
    });

    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

}

private void stopPlaying() {
    if (player.isPlaying()) {
        player.stop();
        player.release();
        initializeMediaPlayer();
    }

    buttonPlay.setEnabled(true);
    buttonStopPlay.setEnabled(false);
    playSeekBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if (player.isPlaying()) {
        player.stop();
    }
}
}
```

Just look at onClick on the above code, because this class works fine to my thinking.

MyService class:

```
package com.etc.etcc;

public class MyService extends Service {
private static final String TAG = "MyService";
private MediaPlayer player;

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "My Service Created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate");


}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "My Service Stopped", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy");
    player.stop();
}

@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startid) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "My Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Log.d(TAG, "onStart");

    player = new MediaPlayer();
    try {
        player.setDataSource("http://50.117.26.26:3953/Live");
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    player.prepareAsync();
    player.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {

        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {

        player.start();

        }
    });
 }
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `onStart` is deprecated method. you should use `onStartCommand` method.
2. Debug your code and check weather there is any Exception or something
3. Also you are using the service so possible that you service will call twice in that case your `onStartCommand` method will be called twice so there you will have to check the startId which you will get as a parameter. **If startId > 1 that means previously your service is started** so you can stop media player and again start a media player with latest source or you can just ignore the second request.
4. If you are not confidence with service you can put your code in the activity and check weather your code is working fine or not after that you can replace this code in the service.